# How can I go about testing games on a console

Tags: unreal, console, playstation3

I was wondering how I could play a game I've made on a console (PS3). I don't want to sell it or anything I just want to test it for now, also do I still have to do that whole registration thing to do this? Oh, I'm also using Unreal Engine 4 for this.

Comment: UE4 does not support the PS3. Did you mean PS4? If so, you’d still need a PS4 test kit, and yes, that whole registration thing… but maybe your best bet would be to make friends with someone who has access to a test kit :-)

Comment: Wait a few years and then playtest it on the PS4 emulator ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unreal Engine 4 doesn't support the PlayStation 3, but it does support the PlayStation 4. It and the Xbox One both use processors built around the AMD Jaguar core, which are comparable to AMD's [Kabini processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_accelerated_processing_unit_microprocessors#.22Kabini.22_.282014.2C_28_nm.2C_SoC.29). This suggests testing your game on a PC with an Athlon 5150 processor as a proxy for performance on a PS4.

Another proxy for PS4 performance is the Xbox One. Since sometime in 2016, anybody with an unbanned Xbox One console, a legit copy of Windows 10, and a Developer Center account ($19 one-time for individuals) can [activate developer mode](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/apps/developer-mode-activation-app-faq).

Once your game is feature-complete and playable with a controller, then you can form a small company (such as LLC or S corporation), register a domain, finish this or another PC game, get a static IP for your office, and [join Sony's developer program](https://partners.playstation.com/apex/PO_AccountAppliPTR?lang=en).